# Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: in async/await block

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to get drawable from URL, that points to an image. But problem is, that in android you shouldn't execute network tasks on the main thread. Because of it, I use async/await block, but the error still occurs all the time. Here is the code:

```
page.Appearing += async(sender, ev3) =>
                    {
                        if ( GetToolbar == null ) return;

                        GetToolbar.Subtitle = viewModel?.SubTitle;

                        if ( viewModel == null ) return;

                        if ( viewModel.AvatarUrl.Contains("?") && !viewModel.AvatarUrl.Contains("gravatar") )
                            viewModel.AvatarUrl = viewModel.AvatarUrl
                                .Substring(0, viewModel.AvatarUrl.IndexOf("?", StringComparison.Ordinal));

                        //var stream = Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(viewModel.AvatarUrl));

                        await SetLogo(viewModel);
 }

private async Task SetLogo(PublicRepositoryPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var url = new URL(viewModel.AvatarUrl);
            var connection = url.OpenConnection();
            var stream = connection.InputStream;
            var logo = await Drawable.CreateFromStreamAsync(stream, viewModel.Title + "_avatar");
            GetToolbar.Logo = logo;
        }
```

Exactly it occurs on this line:

```
var stream = connection.InputStream;
```

If I use OpenInputStream instead of it, then it throws 
Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/6516107

I have checked Internet permission.

It is Xamarin.Forms Android project

**ANSWER:**

```
await Task.Run(async() => {
                            var url = new URL(viewModel.AvatarUrl);
                            var connection = url.OpenConnection();
                            var stream = connection.InputStream;
                            var logo = await Drawable.CreateFromStreamAsync(stream, viewModel.Title + "_avatar");
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>GetToolbar.Logo = logo);
                        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Task.Run` will get you off the main thread and onto a thread in the default Threadpool:

```
await Task.Run(async() => {
  var url = new URL(viewModel.AvatarUrl);
  var connection = url.OpenConnection();
  var stream = connection.InputStream;
  var logo = await Drawable.CreateFromStreamAsync(stream, viewModel.Title + "_avatar");
  GetToolbar.Logo = logo;
});
```

Comment: You missed async keyword before lambda. 
Thank you. It did a trick. Maybe you have some source, that explains it?

Comment: @YuraBabiy Thanks, I fix the missing `async`.

Comment: Just tagging a method with `async` does not cause the method body to run a different thread. Now once it hits an awaited task, that does push it to a thread pool (by default) so it is not blocking the calling thread (thus you have an asynchronous function) and now "off" the thread that started it, in this case, the main UI messaging/looper thread. After the awaited task is complete, the rest of the method continues to execute (these are called `continuations`) and are executed on a thread pool (the default `SynchronizationContext` is thread pool based, but that can be altered...)

Comment: By wrapping everything in your method within an awaited `Task`, we are now on a different thread immediately and Android is happy wth your network calls. In fact we might be executing on a bunch of different threads as each awaited `Task` and its continuations "could" be a different thread, but will never be on the original calling thread as it is the main UI looper thread and that is not available within the Threadpools that the system created. That is also way you had to perform a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` so your UI updates would be executed on the proper thread.