# Cannot read response AsStream because i get NetworkOnMainThreadException in .NET MAUI BLAZOR

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I cannot read as stream because i get NetworkOnMainThreadException error.

this is my code:

```
string requestRoot = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestToSerialize);
        var content = new StringContent(requestRoot, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _httpClient.BaseAddress)
        {
            Content = content
        };
        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();

                if (line!.StartsWith("data:"))
                {
                    if (!line.Contains("[DONE]"))
                    {
                        var data = line.Substring(5).Trim();
                        WEBAPP.Entities.Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WEBAPP.Entities.Root>(data);

                        if (root.choices[0].delta.content != null)
                        {
                            RequestLog.content = root.choices[0].delta.content;
                        }
                        if (root.choices[0].delta.role != null)
                        {
                            RequestLog.role = root.choices[0].delta.role;
                        }
                        RequestLog.index = root.choices[0].index;


                        if (data == "[DONE]")
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        JObject dataObj = JObject.Parse(data);
                        string contentValue = (string)dataObj["choices"][0]["delta"]["content"];
                        Response += contentValue;
                        StateHasChanged();
                        Thread.Sleep(170);

                        Console.WriteLine(line);

                        sb.Append(contentValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

and i get this error:

```
{Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallIntMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 11725
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualInt32Method(String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:line 511
   at Java.IO.InputStream.Read(Byte[] b, Int32 off, Int32 len) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net7.0/android-33/mcw/Java.IO.InputStream.cs:line 282
   at Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/InputStreamInvoker.cs:line 89
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.DelegatingStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.get_EndOfStream()
   at CHAT.Pages.Index.SendRequest() in C:\Users\Mr.Sepi0l\Desktop\MAUI\CHAT\CHAT\Pages\Index.razor.cs:line 85
  --- End of managed Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException stack trace ---
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1667)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:431)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:836)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:824)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:797)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1xStream.java:453)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:437)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:372)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:31)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

  --- End of managed Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException stack trace ---
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1667)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:431)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:836)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:824)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:797)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:213)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:307)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:301)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:197)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1xStream.java:453)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:437)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:372)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:31)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
}
```

I am using .NET MAUI BLAZOR in .NET 7. Does anyone fix this issue?

I am trying something with Task.Run but i still get only first character from response and nothing more. Maybe someone of you get through this and will help ? :-)

##EDIT

This is frontend:

```
@page "/"


<div class="container">
    <div class="response-container" style="padding:10px;">
        @if(Question != "")
        {
            <div class="card" style="background-color:#343541;">
                <h6 class="card-header" style="background-color:#59595c;color:white; text-align:center;">@Question</h6>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Response))
                        {
                            <pre>
                                 <code>
                                   @((MarkupString)RenderMarkdown(Response))
                                 </code>
                            </pre>
                        }
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="edit-form">
        <EditForm id="editForm" Model="@Message" OnValidSubmit="SendRequest" OnInvalidSubmit="Invalid" class="edit-form">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <p>
                <InputTextArea 
                    @onkeyup="Enter"
                    @oninput="Input"
                               @bind-Value="message"
                    style="background-color:#444654;color:#dcce85;font-weight:bold;" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Ask question" 
                   >
                </InputTextArea>
            </p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button class="btn form-button" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button class="btn form-button" @onclick="Resend" type="button">Resend</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                        <button class="btn form-button" @onclick="NewChat" type="button">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: This code is executed on button click. I can tell that this works in blazor-server, but i cannot do this on .net maui blazor.

Comment: in first post..

Comment: No the code that calls that code

Comment: what? @Charlieface

Answer (score 1):

This error will be thrown when you make a network request (or another potentially long running operation) in the Main Thread on the android.So you can create a new thread to read response AsStream. Such as `Thread subthread = new Thread();`.

**Note: If you want to update the UI on the android, you need to make the code about UI run on the Main Thread.**

In addition, you can also try the [`Task.Run(async() => {});`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089391/17455524) to run the code by the thread pool. It will also make the code run on the subthread.

And you can refer to the issue about [NetworkOnMainThreadException when using HttpClient](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5264) on the github.

Comment: this:  Task.Run(async() => {});  - does not work. I will follow your lead to github. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are welcome and you can also try to use the new Thread.@Freelancer